# Shell script: check if any files in one directory are newer than any files in another directory

Tags: shell, timestamp

I want to run a command in a shell script if files in one directory have changed more recently than files in another directory.

I would like something like this

```
if [ dir1/* <have been modified more recently than> dir2/* ]; then
  echo 'We need to do some stuff!'
fi
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003). You'll need to find the newest file in the each directory and compare the two individually; the FAQ tells you how to do all those things.

Comment: If *any* file in `dir1` has changed more recently than *any* file in `dir2`? Or do they have identical structures and you want to compare pairs?

Comment: @BenjaminW., ...I certainly read the pseudocode as implying the former.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, I want to know if any file in dir1 has changed more recently than any file in dir2.

Comment: I think I can use directory mtime "Keep in mind that mtime on directories is that of the most recently added, removed, or renamed file in that directory" since I also want to know if files were added or renamed

Comment: Note that directory mtime **doesn't** cover the time when a file's contents was modified, if the file wasn't renamed. (Some means of doing an edit create a tempfile and rename it over the original, but whether you can count on that being the *only* way used to edit files in this directory...)

Answer (score 2):

As described in [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), broken down here into reusable functions:

```
newestFile() {
  local latest file
  for file; do
    [[ $file && $file -nt $latest ]] || latest=$file
  done
}

directoryHasNewerFilesThan() {
  [[ "$(newestFile "$1"/*)" -nt "$(newestFile "$2" "$2"/*)" ]]
}

if directoryHasNewerFilesThan dir1 dir2; then
  echo "We need to do something!"
else
  echo "All is well"
fi
```

If you want to count the directories themselves as files, you can do that too; just replace `"$(newestFile "$1"/*)"` with `"$(newestFile "$1" "$1"/*)"`, and likewise for the call to `newestFile` for `$2`.

Answer (score 1):

Using /bin/ls

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

dir1=$1
dir2=$2

#get modified time of directories
integer dir1latest=$(ls -ltd --time-style=+"%s" ${dir1} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $6}')
integer dir2latest=$(ls -ltd --time-style=+"%s" ${dir2} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $6}')

#get modified time of the latest file in the directories
integer dir1latestfile=$(ls -lt --time-style=+"%s" ${dir1} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $6}')
integer dir2latestfile=$(ls -lt --time-style=+"%s" ${dir2} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $6}')

#sort the times numerically and get the highest time
val=$(/bin/echo -e "${dir1latest}\n${dir2latest}\n${dir1latestfile}\n${dir2latestfile}" | sort -n | tail -n 1)

#check to which file the highest time belongs to
case $val in
   @(${dir1latest}|${dir1latestfile})) echo $dir1 is latest ;;
   @(${dir2latest}|${dir2latestfile})) echo $dir2 is latest ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, get times stamps of both the folders in machine format(epoch time) then do simple comparison. that's all